# app.yaml / project file structure works on app engine localhost debugger but not on google app engine server

Tags: python, google-app-engine, yaml

This issue is probably a result of my limited understanding of project structures in Python and app engine as well as my limited understanding of the app.yaml file.

I have a python 2.7 project who's file structure looks like this:

```
Project_name
 > src
   app.yaml
   > python
     __init__.py
     > package_folder1
       __init__.py
       package1_file.py
     > package_folder2
       __init__.py
```

My app.yaml file has this in it:

```
- url: /package1/resource1
  script: package_folder1.package1_file1.py
  secure: always
```

This works fine when debugging on localhost using app engine's simulator, but on the server, I am getting this warning (which in this case is an error because the script is not being served) when I try to access the resource `/package1/resource1`:

```
File referenced by handler not found: python.package_folder1.package1_file1.py
```

I also tried changing the line in the app.yaml file to this `script: package_folder1.package1_file1.py` and still got the same error.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Where do you store your yaml file? The package paths are relative to it.

Comment: @sizzzzlerz - I added the location above. Its inside the "src" folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the python folder the entire python runtime?  If so, you should not be including that.

```
Project_name
> src
  app.yaml
  > package_folder1
    __init__.py
    package1_file.py
  > package_folder2
    __init__.py
```

Use slashes instead of periods to specify the script in the app.yaml file:

```
script: package_folder1/package1_file1.py
```

Comment: No, what I was trying to do was put all the python code for the project in the "python" folder.

Comment: Ah.  I think the problem is that in that you need to use slashes instead of periods to specify the script.  script: package_folder1/package1_file1.py

Dunno why it happens to work locally.

Comment: Yup, that was the problem! I think the project structure I have set up leaves a lot to be desired as well with the "python" folder and everything.

Comment: you can name it anything you want.  I'm just easily confused.

Answer (score 1):

What runtime are you using python 2.5 or python 2.7? There are some differences when using one or the other. Also, where in your project structure are you storing the app.yaml file?

For python 2.5 you specify the actual python script, but for python 2.7 you specify the WSGI application. See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Script_Handlers for more details.

The runtime is defined in the app.yaml file with the key runtime.

```
runtime: python   #python 2.5
runtime: python27 #python 2.7
```

Comment: I added the python runtime and app.yaml location to the question above.  The python runtime is 2.7 and app.yaml is located in the "src" folder.